# Kibana fails to connect to Elasticsearch on docker

Tags: windows, docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I am following https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docker.html
and
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.5/docker.html
But it does not seems to work well with kibana, ES works fine.

I tried starting kibana alone, but finally i added it to one docker-compose file.

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.4
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml  
    ports:
    - 5601:5601    

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Kibana.yml is:

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.name: "kibana"
elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
```

I get following error:

> kibana_1          | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-11T08:55:30Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kibana` container isn't on the same network as the two `elasticsearch` containers: it doesn't have a `networks:` block and so is on an automatically-created `default` network, but the two `elasticsearch` containers are on an explicitly-declared `esnet` network.  Since they're not on the same network, inter-container DNS doesn't work.

I'd suggest just deleting all of the `networks:` blocks and using the default network Docker Compose creates for you.  If you want an explicit named network, copy the same `networks: [esnet]` lines into the `kibana:` service block.